# JMeter: single testing vs distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

Straight to the point,

I have used jmeter to load test a website that hosted in apache web server.
When i load test with a single computer (2000 user), the error rate, connect time, and response time is higher than when i load test with 4 computer (500 user each computer, distributed testing).

My question is, what cause distributed testing gave a different and better result than single testing?

Comment: Any feedback on thids answer ?

Comment: i figured it out, thanks for your time and helping answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So many factors related to:

- Your machine configuration is it powerful enough ?, is it correctly configured (OS, network stack, memory ...)
- Your JMeter software configuration, is it running with default ? did you change things for 2000 run ?

You should read this:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Comment: I didn't talk about the web server.
I talk about remote/distribute testing that have better result than single testing.
In my case, I set up the configuration like this :
Number of thread -> 2000
Ramp-up time -> 10 s
Loop -> 1
Http Request Sampler -> I only open a simple web page

Comment: My answer concerned JMeter not your webserver. JMeter configuration is not only about Test Plan.